# Regarding research work.

Tags: discussion

Suppose I have asked some question related to my research and got the answer. May I add that result and proof(obtained on this site) in my research article?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy thanku sir, for your kind reply

Comment: @YaniorWeg Thank you sir

Comment: Closely related: [Papers that originated on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/papers-that-originated-on-math-se) and the linked/related Questions there.

Comment: You could also have a look at this post: [Do I cite Mathematics Stack Exchange in my thesis/paper?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4259) And many of the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4259) are on similar topic.

Comment: *If you cite correctly*, then yes - otherwise it's plagiarism (the obligation to cite appropriately is exactly the same here as it is with respect to any other situation where you learn the proof from an outside source). All data needs to be provided in your text, namely the relevant username(s) (even if they're silly), specific URL(s), and date(s).

Comment: As is mentioned at the bottom of this page, *"Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA"*. And [this license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) requires that 1/ you **give appropriate credit**, and 2/ you **distribute your contributions under the same license**. By contributions, it's meant that you remix, transform, or build upon the material found on this site.